# Postman upload files iteratively in the runner

Tags: file-upload, automated-tests, postman

There are plenty of questions on how to upload a file here, but I wanna run a single request from the runner iteratively, each time uploading a different file. I realize that, in the request Body, I can set the file key as file[] [file[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcGjN.png) and add multiple files, but that is not what I require.

What I wanna do is I want to set the value of the file key to {{some_dynamic_variable}} (like this `file:{{Utterance}}`, and then add a file in the runner with each line indicating the path to a file for each subsequent iteration, like in the screenshot:
[Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11nEr.png)

But it fails to run like that. My question is, first of all, if it's even possible, and if yes, how to indicate the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this trick to use variable in form-data.

1. Setting form-data as normal

[image]

2. Export collection, then edit the collection file

[image]

3. Import collection back to Postman

[image]

4. Variable `{{Utterance}}` can be defined in global, environment or iteration. I've just tested with global scope.

[image]